# One instance application over multiple Windows user accounts

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, mutex, user-accounts

I have used solution of Mutex to disallow opening more than one instance of my application at the same time

but, when i use Switch User in windows and open another user, and try to open the application, it opened normally and can't detect that it's running on other account

how could i solve something like this and disallow opening the application among Logged in Windows User Accounts

i am using code like this

```
Dim onlyInstance As Boolean = False
_mutex = New Mutex(True, "Application Name", onlyInstance)
If Not onlyInstance Then
   MessageBox.Show("Application is already running.", "Error.")
   System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess.Kill()
   System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess.WaitForExit()
End If
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make your mutex global, then it will be visible to all users:

```
mutexName = String.Format("Global\\{{{0}}}", "Application Name");
```

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx):

> A named system mutex can have two levels of visibility. If its name
>   begins with the prefix "Global\", the mutex is visible in all terminal
>   server sessions. If its name begins with the prefix "Local\", the
>   mutex is visible only in the terminal server session where it was
>   created. In that case, a separate mutex with the same name can exist
>   in each of the other terminal server sessions on the server. If you do
>   not specify a prefix when you create a named mutex, it takes the
>   prefix "Local\". Within a terminal server session, two mutexes whose
>   names differ only by their prefixes are separate mutexes, and both are
>   visible to all processes in the terminal server session. That is, the
>   prefix names "Global\" and "Local\" describe the scope of the mutex
>   name relative to terminal server sessions, not relative to processes.

Comment: This is actually the reverse of what the poster is asking for

Answer (score 1):

The technique that I have used for 30 years is to simply have the App try to open (and hold open) a known file for exclusive access when it starts up, and then to exit if it cannot open that file.

I know it's seriously low-tech and retro, but it's simple, always supported and works literally *everywhere*.  I have used it successfully in production code on over half a dozen OS's and in more than a dozen different programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think other, non-admin users, can see the processes of the other users.

What I propose is writing a windows service that runs in the system space. Your program can then connect to it and determine whether to launch or not.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this solution for WPF applications](http://wpfinstanceawareapp.codeplex.com/), it makes use of a Mutex to establish uniqueness but also uses WCF to allow a new instance to communicate with the primary instance.